# Pokemon Bank Switching Gifts pokemiles or battle points

Tags: pokemon-bank

Can you switch between Pokemiles and Battle Points? If so, can you tell me how?

Answer (score 3):

Yes.  Every time you earn enough points in Poké Bank for transfer to your game, the application will ask you whether you want them in Poké Miles or BP.  However, you can't change any points that have already been sent to your game.